# Adding frame to picture in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, photo-gallery

i would like to add a frame to a picture using Java and Javafx and then save the framed picture. What would be the best way to do that?

For example say I have a photo of a landscape and want to add a frame to it. The framed photo should look like this: [image: saved image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add two images, first the frame, then the image, to the same canvas like this:

```
GraphicsContext gc1 = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc1.drawImage(frameimage,0,0,image.getFitWidth()+20,image.getFitHeight()+20);
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.drawImage(i,10,10,image.getFitWidth(),image.getFitHeight());
```

and then save them as png (or whatever format you like) using the *canvas.snapshot* function:

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter =new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("png files (*.png)", "*.png");

fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
Stage primaryStage = (Stage) canvas.getScene().getWindow();

File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(primaryStage);
if(file != null){
        try {
            WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage((int)canvas.getWidth(), (int)canvas.getHeight());
            canvas.snapshot(null, writableImage);
            RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(writableImage, null);
            File file1 = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+".png");

            file.renameTo(file1);

            ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "png", file1);


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
}
```